# Comparing 2 tables with same structure in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Well, i have a table called "Lov(List of Values)" that have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE lov
(
  tipo integer NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  codigo character varying(255),
  descricao character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT lov_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

I have another table called lov_tmp with the same structure above, the only diff between this 2 tables is that lov_tmp contains the original data from a central database and lov contains the data from local database.

I need comparer this 2 tables, finding the values:
 1- Inserted in lov_tmp and didn't in lov, 
 2- Changed/Updated in lov_tmp and didn't in lov,
 3- Deleted in lov_tmp and didn't in lov.

I can't comparer the ID's (PK), because they are differents in each database, i just can comparer the columns "codigo, tipo and descricao".

Some ideia?

Comment: If the PKs are different it is not possible to know if a row was updated or just inserted/deleted. You can only know if a row exists in one table and not in the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of those fields you do have (codigo, tipo and descricao) can be be used as a unique key, or a composite key.. you can just do select into a temp, filtering out the ones that don't exist in one (or the other)

Not sure how the postgressql syntax would look but here is the basic idea of selecting into a temp everything from one thats NOT IN the other table.

```
SELECT 
     l.*
INTO 
     #someTempTable
FROM 
    lov l
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT <<someUniqueOrCompositeKey>> FROM lov_tmp)
```

That would tell you which rows don't match up.